# DHCP dns stopped working on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, dns, dhcp, systemd-resolved, resolvconf

I have setup new ubuntu 18.04 server which has dhcp assigned ip and dns 192.168.120.62 , after setup when i checked i waw able to get result using nslookup for local dns entries of 192.168.120.62 but nlsookup were showing nameserver 127.0.0.1:53 but after sometime it started failing with error name of service not known for ping response even for nslookup i was getting nxdomain , i checked dns server its working properly but still i am facing issue can you guide me what is the correct method if i want to assign dns to server using dhcp permanently

Comment: Can you get a  printscreen/output of  ifconfig? , why are you setting dns@127.0.0.1:53

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know which name servers you would like to use, you can add them to Netplan.

Look in `/etc/netplan` for a `.yaml` file and open it. For example:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
```

You are going to see something that looks like this:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            dhcp6: false
            match:
                macaddress: 00:01:02:03:04:05
            set-name: eth0
    version: 2
```

***NOTE:** Yours will probably look a little different. Do not worry if your file is just a few lines long.*

Create a new `nameservers` item under the device section followed by an `addresses` item. Note that spacing is *very* important here.

```
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            dhcp6: false
            nameservers:
                addresses: [1.2.3.4, 5.6.7.8]
            match:
                macaddress: 00:01:02:03:04:05
            set-name: eth0
    version: 2
```

Do change the IP addresses here to *proper* addresses. If you would like to use one of the more popular services for DNS, here are the addresses:

| Provider | Addresses |
| --- | --- |
| Google | `[8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]` |
| Cloudflare | `[1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1]` |
| OpenDNS | `[208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220]` |
| Level3 | `[209.244.0.3, 209.244.0.4]` |

Once done, save the file and then apply it:

```
$ sudo netplan apply
```

Test the DNS Servers are being used with this:

```
$ systemd-resolve --status | grep 'DNS Servers' -A2
```

You should see something that looks like this:

```
         DNS Servers: 1.1.1.1
                      1.0.0.1
```

Done.